# Error when trying to chain class method in controller in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I am trying to chain a few class methods from my User model to perform a faceted search. When the code runs it returns the following error

```
undefined method `has_skill_categories' for #<Array:0x000001026d3de8>
```

Can you show me how to call these methods from the model in the controller by chaining them together?

Here is my code:

**experts_controller.erb**

```
class ExpertsController < ApplicationController
  layout 'experts'

  def index

    @users = User.text_search(params[:query])
              .has_marketing_assets(params[:marketing_platforms])
              .has_skill_categories(params[:skills])
              .search_for_user_country(params[:user][:country])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**user.erb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :marketing_assets
  has_many :marketing_platforms, through: :marketing_assets
  has_many :my_skills
  has_many :skills, through: :my_skills
  has_many :past_works
  has_many :past_work_types, through: :past_works

  validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true

  include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :search, against: [:first_name, :last_name, :company, :description, :job_title, :website, :email, :country, :city, :state],
                  using: {tsearch: {dictionary: 'english'}},
                  associated_against: {:skills => :name, :past_works => [:description, :title, :url], :marketing_assets => [:platform, :description, :url], :past_work_types => :name,
                                       :marketing_platforms => :name}

  def self.text_search(query)
    if query.present?
      search(query)
    else
      User.all
    end
  end


  def self.has_marketing_assets(platforms)
    if platforms.present?
      @platforms = MarketingPlatform.all
      platforms_count = platforms.count
      where_clause_platforms = 'SELECT *
                                FROM Users
                                WHERE Users.id IN
                                (SELECT Users.id
                                FROM users
                                INNER JOIN marketing_assets ON users.id = marketing_assets.user_id
                                WHERE marketing_assets.marketing_platform_id= '
      n = 0

      if platforms.count > 0

        platforms.each do |platform|
          n += 1
          where_clause_platforms = where_clause_platforms + platform
          if n < platforms_count
            where_clause_platforms = where_clause_platforms + ' OR marketing_assets.marketing_platform_id= '
          end
        end

        where_clause_platforms = where_clause_platforms + " GROUP BY users.id
                                                          HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT marketing_assets.marketing_platform_id) = #{platforms.count})"
        find_by_sql(where_clause_platforms)

      else
        return
      end
    end
  end


  def self.has_skill_categories(skills)
    if skills.present?

      skills_count = skills.count
      where_clause_skills = 'SELECT *
                                      FROM Users
                                      WHERE Users.id IN
                                      (SELECT Users.id
                                      FROM users
                                      INNER JOIN my_skills ON users.id = my_skills.user_id
                                      WHERE my_skills.skill_id= '
      n = 0

      if skills_count > 0

        skills.each do |skill|
          n += 1
          where_clause_skills = where_clause_skills + skill
          if n < skills_count
            where_clause_skills = where_clause_skills + ' OR my_skills.skill_id= '
          end
        end

        where_clause_skills = where_clause_skills + "GROUP BY users.id
                                                        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT my_skills.skill_id) = #{skills.count})"
        find_by_sql(where_clause_skills)


      else
        return
      end
    end
  end


  def self.search_for_user_country(country)
    if country.present?
      where('country = ?', "#{country}")
    else
      return
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, in order to chain your methods, you should be returning an ActiveRecord query object. Calling `return` without an argument will return nil, which is not chainable. You should instead return `where()`, which would return the current collection with no modifications.

The reason you are getting the error above is because `find_by_sql` [returns results as an array](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Querying/find_by_sql), not a scoped query like `where` does. So, as you are doing it now, I don't think there's a way to chain them. But that's probably a good thing because it will force you to rewrite your queries and scopes without raw sql statements.

I would highly recommend reviewing the [Rails Guides on Active Record Querying](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html), and avoid writing raw SQL statements if at all possible in a Rails project. This could greatly simplify your methodology. You should **never** put raw user input into SQL queries, which it looks like you are doing in multiple places in your code. Rails provides an advanced query interface to protect you and your data, and the SQL statement you are building above is extremely vulnerable to injection attacks.

With the correct combination of `scope` and association calls (which can use scopes defined on the associated model), you could probably clean a lot of that code up and greatly improve the security of your application.

**Update**

It looks to me like your queries could greatly be simplified using scopes and `#merge`.

```
def self.has_skill_categories(skill_ids)
  joins(:my_skills).merge Skill.where(id: skill_ids)
end

def self.has_marketing_assets(platform_ids)
  joins(:marketing_assets).merge MarketingAsset.where(marketing_platform_id: platform_ids)
end
```

Those may not get you exactly what you're going for, but from what I can tell, it should be close, and show you how you can use the built-in ActiveRecord query interface to build complex queries without ever writing any raw SQL.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to help me understand what I am doing wrong. Do you recommend using the Squeel gem to write complex SQL like this. I don't think it is possible to use the out of the box Rails solution.

Comment: I would appreciate anyone giving me some help rewriting this SQL statement using Tails active record. maybe even using the Squeel Gem as I am using Rails 4.  SELECT "users".*   
FROM "users"    
WHERE "users"."id" 
IN (SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users"  
INNER JOIN marketing_assets ON users.id = marketing_assets.user_id 
WHERE  marketing_assets.marketing_platform_id= 3 
GROUP BY users.id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT marketing_assets.marketing_platform_id) = 1)

Comment: It looks like you might be trying to search where something is in a collection of ids. ActiveRecord can do this in a few different ways. `MyModel.where(product_id: [1,4,5])`. You would probably also benefit from the `#merge` method. Check out #1 on this post: http://blog.mitchcrowe.com/blog/2012/04/14/10-most-underused-activerecord-relation-methods/