# Re-writing a SQL Query using Active Record or the Squeel Gem in Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, squeel

I am having a lot of problems rewriting this SQL Query in Squeel or straight Active Record using Ruby on Rails 4.

All 3 numbers in the query need to be passed to the query before execution. The SQL Query is below.

```
SELECT "users".* 
FROM "users"  
WHERE "users"."id" 
IN (SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users"  
INNER JOIN marketing_assets ON users.id = marketing_assets.user_id 
WHERE  marketing_assets.marketing_platform_id= 3 
GROUP BY users.id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT marketing_assets.marketing_platform_id) = 1)
```

You can find out more detail about how it is being used at [Error when trying to chain class method in controller in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21505042/error-when-trying-to-chain-class-method-in-controller-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 0):

```
marketing_assets_id = 3
limit_marketing_assets = 1
User.joins(:marketing_assets).where(:marketing_assets => {:marketing_platform_id => marketing_assets_id}).group(:users => :id).having("COUNT(DISTINCT marketing_assets.marketing_platform_id) = #{limit_marketing_assets}")
```

Comment: Thanks @AhmadHussain, the marketing_platform_id in the where clauses value is a variable and could also be 2 or more values. Also the value '1' in  'COUNT(DISTINCT marketing_assets.marketing_platform_id) = 1' is also variable depending on how many values there are in the where clause. How would this be rewritten? Also is it easier to use Squeel for this?

Comment: Squeel is good but its not a good practice to always use some gem to perform a task because in this case this work can be done without squeel that's why i didn't used it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query I ended up writing using Squeel. It works for me.

```
User.where{users.id.in(User.joins{marketing_assets}
.where((['marketing_assets.marketing_platform_id = ?' ] * platforms.count)
.join(' OR '), *platforms).group{users.id}
.having{{marketing_assets => 
{COUNT(DISTINCT(marketing_assets.marketing_platform_id)) => platforms.count }}})}
```